# hdmi/dsi 5 inch oled capacitive touch screen

Tags: hdmi, displays, touchscreen, sbc

I am searching for an OLED display with a capacitive touch screen which I can use with my sbc. I am not 100% sure yet, but most likely I'll settle with the RPI Compute module, so DSI displays which work with it are also an option.

I would like to have a display which can be used without a pen and have a "modern" feel and look, as well as good image quality.

This display would be perfect, however, it is discontinued and I was unable to find anything comparable.

https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1779.html

Display size should be about 5-6 inch 16:9.

As long as the price is reasonable, I don't really have a price limit.

Comment: It generally adds value to posts if you specify an upper price limit, or alternatively specify that you don't have one.